# Convert hex value to list of boolean values

Tags: javascript

This is an odd one, but stick with me here.  Given a hex value (from 00-FF), I need to convert it into binary, then from there convert it into an object with the key being the 'place' of each bit, and the value being a boolean.

That was an awkward explanation.  Here's an example:

Given 'FF', I need to translate that into binary (`parseInt(<hex value>, 16).toString(2)` works for that job).

Now that FF has become `1111 1111`, I need to convert that into an object that looks like so:

```
{ 
  "1": true, 
  "2": true, 
  "4": true, 
  "8": true, 
  "16":true, 
  "32":true,
  "64": true, 
  "128": true
}
```

As another example, given the hex value 'A6', that becomes `1010 0110` which would become:

```
{ 
  "1": false, 
  "2": true, 
  "4": true, 
  "8": false, 
  "16":false, 
  "32":true, 
  "64": false, 
  "128": true
}
```

The only thing I'm looking to do is that final conversion from binary -> object.

I know I can do it with a simple loop, but I was wondering if there's any cool comp-sci way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: I can think of many cool more complicated ways to do it, but a loop seems in order in this case. Just don't calculate the numeric keys every time, do it once and store them.

Comment: Note that you don't need to convert the value into a string: `x = parseInt('A6', 16) // 255; for (n = 1; x > 0; x = x >> 1, n = n * 2) { console.log(n, x % 2 == 1) }`

Comment: @Hamms You should really post that (with a little extra) as an answer. It's trivial to go from that to the object OP wants to generate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, as I mentioned in a comment above, you don't need to convert the value to a string; if you keep it as a decimal integer, you can use the [bitshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operators to get your binary values.

```js
var x = parseInt('A6', 16); // 166
var result = {};

for (var n = 1; x > 0; x = x >> 1, n = n * 2) {
   result[n] = x % 2 == 1;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
```

Comment: This one looks like winner winner.  Thank you for your input!  I've never used bitshift in a practice, seeing as how I'm a lowly ruby dev.

Comment: @KieranE Few developers who only use high-level languages ever learn to bitshift, but if you ever work programming directly against hardware -- it is the only way to go.  Added fun is when you can back 16 boolean values into a 16bit integer.  Back when RAM was tight, that was common.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without going to an intermediate binary string, but if you're just stuck on that final step you can do something like the following:

```
var bin = parseInt('0xa6', 16).toString(2);

Array.from(bin).reduce(function(byte, bit, index) {
    byte[1 << bin.length - index - 1] = bit === '1';
    return byte;
}, {});
```

[JavaScript demo](https://repl.it/CXMj)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one **long** liner

```js
const x = parseInt('A6', 16).toString(2).split('').reduceRight((last, bit, i, arr) => Object.assign(last, {[`${1 << (arr.length - i - 1)}`]: bit == 1}), {})
console.log(x)
```

It assumes that you're in an environment that supports [computed keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) (which is available in ES2015)

Answer (score -1):

Here it is.

```
var x = {}, s = 1;
(0x10100110).toString(16).split('').reverse().map(a => {
    x[s] = !!~~a;
    s *= 2;
});
```

Comment: Care to explain the method behind your madness?

Comment: I mean.... it works.  But that's the diciest string of code I've seen in all me days